# VueJS: Highlight an entire sentence when you hover over a word in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using VueJS. I have a scenario where I have some content inside a `div` with class `explainer` (multiple paragraphs).

My challenge is to allow a user to hover over any word inside the div. On hover, the entre sentence should get highlighted in a different background, and then the information about the hovered-over word and the highlighted sentence should be shown in another div.

If I had pre-defined word/phrase to hover over, then it was easy, as I could use the `@mouseover` event to trigger this. But in my case, it's a full paragraph, and I don't know which word/sentence the user is going to click.

I've created a fiddle to illustrate this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rus72fzn/1/

Comment: You are asking to work with text as if it was DOM. This is not a happy path to go down. The most important question however: where is the text coming from?

Comment: I know it is difficult. But there should be some way. Maybe we can wrap each sentence in a span and then work from there. And the text comes from database and is stored in Vuex store. So, one idea is to that when the text loads, we parse it to add a span to each sentence. and then work from there.

Comment: I did not realize how much I forgot Vue. Alright so in essence what you can do is take the text in as a prop, break it down into arrays of words. `[[word1, word2], [word3, word4]]` and use that to render the html in the template. Add whatever events you need on top of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just implemented a way to do this by dividing your text into `<span>` tags.

(made it a little prettier)

http://jsfiddle.net/zt2s41yj/

This example isn't super pretty, but it does work and you can see the mechanism.  You'd probably want to build the template from the raw text as well.

UPDATE:  here's a version that does both sentence and word highlighting, generating the spans automatically from the 'content' data field.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/nvsLpxfh/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the good direction. How do I read the text inside a span using refs. this.$refs[id] returns an object, but in console it looks like just the full span element.

Comment: You see that in the example where I am showing the selected sentence. this.$refs[id] is the span element. this.$refs[id].innerText is the text within.

Comment: yes, thanks this worked for me. Since I wanted boh the sentence and the word information, is it possible to extend this example to get informtion about the sentence as well as the selected word? Iam afraid it will look very complicated.

Comment: It's definitely possible, but I think to do words as well, you'll want to implement a way of autogenerating the template or you'll go crazy.  This will be pretty involved; beyond the scope of answering your basic question.  It would be fun to build.  Enjoy. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I've understood and focus on building template to wrap sentences with spans. I will share here when I have it. I have one more query. In each span, we are mouseover and mouseLeave events. Is it possible to not add these in every span and have kind of a global way to trigger these?

Comment: I don't know of any way to not have to add them to each span, but since you are automating it anyway, it won't be a big deal.  One thing to note: the mouseover event will get captured by the highest level, so you should only have them on the word spans, and pass both the word and sentence refs to the function.  Looking forward to seeing what you come up with.  Happy to help if you run into snags.

Comment: Thanks. I started working on it. And frankly speaking, I'm completely lost on how to begin such templating. I created another fiddle based on your fiddle, and kind of created a template on how I expect my input data to be. The input content will have some p and span tags already. Will post another question seeking help on it. But here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8ho4f3p6/